# Organizing data into nested dictionaries: Error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to store data points in a list with keys that correspond to the date the data points were collected (the dates in my files range between 2 and 9 months). I would like the dictionary to look like this:

```
{year : { month : {day : [datapoint(x24)]}}}
```

Before I included defaultdict, my code would report a key error:

```
File "test_file3.py", line 35, in <module>
  my_dict[year][month][day].append(float(row[SENSOR]))
KeyError: '2018'
```

With defaultdict included, it gives an error:

```
File "test_file3.py", line 35, in <module>
    my_dict[year][month][day].append(float(row[SENSOR]))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

HOWEVER, i know what I am appending actually is a float. So, why is it failing (apart from my poor programming skills). If it is mad my value is a float, how can I get around this? (I need that value to be a float).

```
infile = open('/Users/joshuaclarkgilman/Documents/5G0E3577 4May18-1146.csv', 
'r')
outfile = open('/Users/joshuaclarkgilman/Documents/test_file.csv', 'w')

from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

#functions here

for row in infile:
row = row.strip()
row = row.split(",")
if row[0] == "\ufeff5G0E3577" or row[0] == "2015 records" or row[0] == "Measurement Time":
   continue
else:
    year = Year_Function(row[0].split("/"))
    month = Month_Function(row[0].split("/"))
    day = Day_Function(row[0].split("/"))

    my_dict[year][month][day].append(float(row[SENSOR]))

infile.close()
```

Comment: `year`, `month` or `day`... or `SENSOR` (can't see what it is)

Comment: Yes-year, month, day are all strings. I thought this error applied only to the values I am attempting to append to my list (value in dictionary). Year, month, day are to be keys in my dictionary...

Comment: What does the `SENSOR` variable look like? It seems to be what's causing the problem, maybe it isn't an integer, so `row[SENSOR]` is not valid syntax.